# alpine krb5 install kerberos commands missing in docker container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, kerberos

I have created a docker image based on alpine 3.8 that includes krb5. I can then create a container and I can see that krb5 packages are installed but none of the kerberos commands are in the /bin e.g kinit klist

I also included all the listed dependencies in the image build but struggling to understand why the commands are missing ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information, like the OS you are on, the Dockerfile you have tried etc.

Comment: The files you are mentioning are not in /bin but in /usr/bin: 
 https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=krb5&branch=v3.8&repo=main&arch=x86_64

Comment: they are not added to /usr/bin either . Real mystery

Comment: @ScubaMan please follow what Edward has suggested in the first comment. Put more info in the question..otherwise is hard to help.